# ElasticSearch - common query with cutoff, score high frequency words only when all low frequency words are matched

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to use "https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html" but cannot make one particular thing to work:
Add high-frequency words scores to total score, ONLY if all low-frequency words from query has been matched.

Tried using `"low_freq_operator": "and"` but it makes all low-frequency words from query required - which I don't know.

Also - if I use

```
"minimum_should_match": {
    "low_freq" : "50%",
}
```

Does it mean that if query has 4 low-frequency words, document with 2 of those will be returned as a hit, but document with only 1 of query words will not be returned right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For [Common Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html)

### **Low Frequency Words**

- More important
- You can construct query to return documents in which all words of query string

  - *`must be present`* (make use of `"low_freq_operator": "and"`)
  - *`only some of them`* (make use of `"low_freq_operator": "or"`
  - *`some percentage of them`* (make use of `minimum_should_match`)

### High Frequency Words

- Less Important.
- You can construct query to `influence the score` in which all stop words in query string

  - *`must be considered`* (make use of `"high_freq_operator": "and"`)
  - *`only some of them`* (make use of `"high_freq_operator": "or"`)
  - *`some percentage of them`* (make use of `minimum_should_match`)
- Only influence the relevancy score.
- If no low frequency words exists, then its a typical `should` clause of all terms in query string

### How does it categorize words as less frequent or more frequent

As per the [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html),

> Terms are allocated to the high or low frequency groups based on the
>   cutoff_frequency, which can be specified as an absolute frequency
>   (>=1) or as a relative frequency (0.0 .. 1.0)....
>
> Perhaps the most interesting property of this query is that it adapts
>   to domain specific stopwords automatically. For example, on a video
>   hosting site, common terms like "clip" or "video" will automatically
>   behave as stopwords without the need to maintain a manual list.

### How it works with example

From this [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html),

The common terms query `is a modern alternative to stopwords which improves the precision and recall of search results` (by taking stopwords into account), without sacrificing performance.

Let's say I have below documents:

```
Document 1: Is there stairway to this path?
Document 2: Is there a stairway to heaven?
Document 3: Stairway to heaven
..... 
.....
```

Now say your search query is as below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "common": {
            "body": {
                "query": "stairway to heaven",
                "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
                "low_freq_operator": "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you use `and` result would be `Document 3 followed by Document 2` only. And when you make use of `or`, result would be `Document 3, Document 2, Document 1` respectively.

So when you use `or`, high frequency word i.e. `to` would be used here to influence the score. In a similar way the `high_freq_operator` would apply for stop words however it would again be only used to influence the score.

So for your first query, hope the above explanation would suffice and as for below query,

> Does it mean that if query has 4 low-frequency words, document with 2
>   of those will be returned as a hit, but document with only 1 of query
>   words will not be returned right?

**Yes, that's correct.**

Hope it helps!